# how can i store an id selected from an association array in a rails session variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-variables

I understand perfectly well how to store an id in session. You just go into your controller and do something like

```
@object = Object.find_by(params[:id)
session[:first_object] = @object
```

But what if I have a whole bunch of different objects in my view, and only need to pass one to the session? I can't use `hidden_fields`. Normally I'd pass it as an argument to `form_for` but I would prefer that the object ID not display in the url.

```
<% @owned_objects.each do |obj| %>
 <%= form_for [obj, @wizard], as: :wizard, url: object_one_wizard_path(obj) do |f| %>
 bla bla
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you want all items in the same session key or separate keys for each object?

Comment: @Mark I just want the id for whichever object the user picks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, saving the `id` in `session` requires some *user action* (to choose which one).

You will need to send the *data* in `params` and show it in the URL **or** send it in the `request body` of a `POST` method, requiring you to use a `hidden_field`. If you don't want to **show** your `id` being sensitive data, you need to create some workaround.

I suggest you use some encryption method to pass your data in the parameters, as your primary concern seems to be that you don't want the id to be visible. There are many encryption methods and libraries out there, this is only my proposed solution.

I created a `custom_route` that will receive `encrypted_id` so you don't have to write a `hidden_field` in the form.

```
get "/set_id/:encrypted_id" => "your_controller#set_encrypted_id", as: :set_id_route
```

And in the view, use the `custom_route` along a `MessageEncryptor` as follows:

```
<% cookies[:salt] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32) %>
<% cookies[:pass] = 'some_password' %>
<% key = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(cookies[:pass]).generate_key(cookies[:salt], 32) %>
<% crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(key) %>
<% @owned_objects.each do |obj| %>
  <%= form_for [obj, @wizard], 
               url: set_id_route(encrypted_id: crypt.encrypt_and_sign(obj.id)), # Or however you send the id
               as: :wizard, method: :get do |f| %>
      bla bla
      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The id will be send in the URL but it won't be readable.

And then in the controller that you want to receive the request decrypt it and set it in `session`.

```
def set_encrypted_id
  key = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(cookies[:pass]).generate_key(cookies[:salt], 32)
  crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(key)
  session[:id] = crypt.decrypt_and_verify params[:encrypted_id]
  render json: { session_id: 'ok' }
end
```

I wrote this example reading and setting `cookies` for you to easily reproduce it, but they should be written in your database or in `ENV` variables. In my solution, some things are not necesarry, like the method being `:get` or that the `encrypted_id` is sent in the URL params (it could be send in the `request body` of another method), but the idea is the same. I hope this answer is usefull to you: If you need user interaction, you need to comunicate it somehow.